# Join Custom object with regular object

Tags: soql, soap-api, contact, relationships, joined-reports

I'm very new with Salesforce. I've been reading [this page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) trying to figure out how to do joins. All the objects were created before I jumped on this project.

I have one custom object called :  Person_Project_Junction__c and another one called Contact.

My query looks like this:

```
 SELECT
      Person_Project_Junction__c.Id,
      Person_Project_Junction__c.Person_First_Name__c,
      Person_Project_Junction__c.Person_Last_Name__c
    FROM
      Person_Project_Junction__c
```

I need to access a field in the Contact object called `Industry__c` . I tried doing this query:

```
  SELECT
          Person_Project_Junction__c.Id,
          Person_Project_Junction__c.Person_First_Name__c,
          Person_Project_Junction__c.Person_Last_Name__c,
          (SELECT Industry__c FROM Contact)
        FROM
          Person_Project_Junction__c
```

But of course, it doesnt work. How would I be able to do this join? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to prefix fields with the Object's API Name.

Try this query to make sure it works fine:

```
list<Person_Project_Junction__c> myList = [SELECT Id,
                                                 Person_First_Name__c,
                                                 Person_Last_Name__c,
                                           FROM Person_Project_Junction__c];
```

Now, my question is this:  Is there a lookup field to `Contact` on the `Person_Project_Junction__c` object?  Assuming yes, there is, and the lookup field is called `Contact__c`, try this:

```
list<Person_Project_Junction__c> myList = [SELECT Id,Person_First_Name__c,
                                                  Person_Last_Name__c,
                                                  Contact__r.Industry__c
                                           FROM Person_Project_Junction__c];
```

---

**Example:**  Let's say on the Custom Object `myCustomObject__c` you have a lookup field called `MyLookupField__c` to another sObject, say `AnotherObject__c`.  If you want to query `AnotherObject__c`'s field `AnImportantField__c`, do the following query:

```
list<myCustomObject__c> myCustomObjList=[SELECT id, MyLookupField__r.AnImportantField__c
                                         FROM myCustomObject__c
                                         WHERE ...];
```

---

**Update:**

Since you only need the SOQL query, here it is:

```
SELECT Id,Person_First_Name__c,
       Person_Last_Name__c,
       Contact__r.Industry__c
FROM Person_Project_Junction__c
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. It gives me this error: MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: list

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure if I have a lookup field, but I'm still getting MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: list. I'm going to check about the lookup field

Comment: Are you using my updated SOQL queries?  I think you error is because you may have `(SELECT Industry__c FROM Contact)` in your SELECT statement.  I don't normally use sub-queries in my SELECT statements (so I'm not an expert on it) though I know it's possible & useful.

Comment: Yes. I copy pasted them. I think my the problem has to do with the word list in front of the query. BTW. I'm using PHP and SOAP to get the data.

Comment: oh yea, totally!  I thought you were doing this with Apex code (in a Class or Trigger in Salesforce).  You don't need to list part at all.  I'll add an update to my response

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding! I tried the update, now I'm getting this: Contact__r.Industry__c ^ ERROR at Row:20:Column:8 Didn't understand relationship 'Contact__r' in field path. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11952/discussion-between-amatorvitae-and-raygo)